# how file holes in linux actually work

Tags: linux, io, operating-system, filesystems

I'm kind of confused about how file holes work on linux:

```
  int fd = open("/tmp/file1", O_RDWR | O_TRUNC);
  write(fd, "bbbb", 4);
  lseek(fd, SEEK_SET, 10000);
  write(fd, "aaaa", 4);
  lseek(fd, SEEK_SET, 50);
  write(fd, "cccc", 4);
  close(fd);
```

why does cat /tmp/file1 produce

```
bbbbaaaacccc
```

? shouldn't it be bbbcccaaa? since aaaa is written at offset of 10000?

update: lseek's return -1 with EINVAL.

Comment: Are you sure that `lseek` is successful in all calls? You do not check its result code.

Comment: it returns EINVAL, but why?

Comment: For the reasons given in the man page.

Comment: Your lseeks are doing nothing because there is nothing in the file to seek to. You are just doing sequential writes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since "Are you sure that lseek is successful in all calls? You do not check its result code." helped identify a problem I would recomend just add after your filesystem calls:

```
  int res = lseek(fd, 10000, SEEK_SET);
  if (res == -1) {
    perror("lseek has failed");
    return 1;
  }
```

You problem is that you use parameters in a wrong order:

```
lseek(fd, SEEK_SET, 10000); /* WRONG order for second and third parametes ! */
```

The correct order:

```
lseek(fd, 10000, SEEK_SET);
```

Here is a man lseek:

```
off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence);

The lseek() function repositions the file offset of the open file
description associated with the file descriptor fd to the argument
offset according to the directive whence as follows:

SEEK_SET
      The file offset is set to offset bytes.

SEEK_CUR
      The file offset is set to its current location plus offset bytes.

SEEK_END
      The file offset is set to the size of the file plus offset
              bytes.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, as I already commented it returns EINVAL:
the resulting  file  offset  would  be negative, or beyond the end of a seekable device.

but how do I create file hole then?

Comment: My copy of the `lseek` manpage says: "**EINVAL:** *whence* is not valid.  Or: the resulting file offset would be negative, or beyond the end of a seekable device."  You are getting EINVAL for the first of these reasons (*whence* is not valid), because you have the parameters in the wrong order, as Sergei says.